# Maven release branch fails with error=7, Argument list too long

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

We have recently migrated our multimodule(each module with a pom.xml) repository from SVN to GIT.SCM connection in all pom.xml files updated from svn to git.

When i am trying to create a branch from git repository using maven release plugin it fails with the below error

"Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:branch (default-cli) on project intgr: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. Error while executing command. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "/bin/sh" (in directory "/u01/remote-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/IN-CDBFG-JOB1/mahirepository"): error=7, Argument list too long -> [Help 1]"

On examining logs i understand below command generated this error.

"[INFO] Checking in modified POMs... [INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /u01/remote-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/IN-CDBFG-JOB1/mahirepository && git add -- intgr-parent/pom.xml archetypes/pom.xml and 1000 more pom files "

Is there a way i can workaround or fix this issue?

Maven version : Apache Maven 3.0.4 
JDK version : 1.7.0_01

Maven command :

mvn -s ./settingsBamboo.xml --batch-mode release:branch -DbranchName=${bamboo.branchname}  -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=true -DsuppressCommitBeforeBranch=true -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DremoteTagging=false -DupdateBranchVersions=false -X

Comment: I recommend first to update your maven-release-plugin version secondly I recommend to upgrade your Maven version..and also upgrade Java version...

Comment: Tried with below updated versions,still facing same issue.

Maven release plugin : 2.5 , Maven : 3.5.0 , JDK : 1.8.0_212

Answer (score 0):

I am currently facing this problem as well, but I got a bit further on this.
The issue has nothing to do with Java or Maven, it's a Linux limitation.

using `getconfig MAX_ARGS` you can find the max amount of bytes you can use as arguments.

Large maven commands can easily go beyond this, and the amount of bytes differs largely per distro.

Check the amount of bytes you can use, and try to get your command below that.

You could for example move into the build dir first, and then run the command relative.

Another solution would be to increase the amount of usable space, but I have so far not gotten that working.

If anyone does or you have fixed this yourself, let me know.